# Showing all rows where two columns average is greater than 60

Tags: r

How would I show (display) all rows of a data set whose average of columns 1 and columns 2 is great than 60

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean the average by row, and that the data frame is named `yourdata`, something like this should work:

```
yourdata[rowMeans(yourdata[1:2]) > 60, ]
```